# Dictionary of lists or separate lists?

Tags: python

So which is better?

```
books = {'titles': [], 'descriptions': [], 'pages': []}
```

or

```
book_titles = []
book_descriptions = []
book_pages = []
```

I'm just curious, is there any difference at all?

Comment: Depends what application you want.  You'll need to be more specific about the parameters of your situation or I'm afraid this question isn't going to turn out well

Comment: Do you want to add or remove lists later on, pass on the data together to other functions, etc.? This all depends on *how you use the data*.

Comment: Module-level variables are stored in a dict object too, so this doesn't change anything, conceptually speaking.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what is this data structure for and how it would be used.

One thing I've noticed is that in both examples you've provided there is no relation between each description, title and pages. In other words, there is no `Book` model/entity. You cannot simply define which title corresponds to which description.

You may want to have a list of dictionaries, or `Book` classes. Or, you can make use of [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Book = namedtuple('Book', ('title', 'description', 'pages'))
>>> book1 = Book(title='War and Peace', description='Worth reading', pages=1225)
>>> book1.title
'War and Peace'
>>> book1.pages
1225
>>> book2 = Book(title='Crime and Punishment', description='Mental anguishes', pages=718)
>>> book2.title
'Crime and Punishment'
>>> books = [book1, book2]
>>> [book.title for book in books]
['War and Peace', 'Crime and Punishment']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list you want to use depends on a parameter, in this case 'titles', 'descriptions', 'pages', then using the dictionary might be the better solution:

```
def show_book_info(list_name):
    print books[list_name]
```

In case that you know exactly when and where to use the list, stick with the second, i.e. three independent lists:

```
def show_book_infos():
    print 'title: %s' % book_titles
    print 'description: %s' % book_descriptions
    print '#pages: %s' % book_pages
```